# Query for an input state that has been consumed in the transaction

Tags: corda

Let say, I have defined two states `StateA` and `StateB` and executed the following actions.

- Create `StateA` with no inputs. (NoInput -> `StateA-sa1`)
- Change one of the parameter on `StateA`. (`StateA-sa1` -> `StateA-sa2`)
- Create `StateB` with unconsumed `StateA` as input. (`StateA-sa2` -> `StateB-sb1`)

Is it possible to construct a single query to get current unconsumed `StateB` (`StateB-sb1`) and inputs(`StateA-sa2`) that went into creating this state?

Answer (score 2):

As of Corda 3.1, no. It's not possible to achieve this with a single query. You actually need to perform three steps:

1. Query the vault for the current unconsumed `StateB`

   ```
   val stateBStateAndRef = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<StateB>().states.single()
   ```
2. Use the `StateRef` of the retrieved state to load the corresponding transaction

   ```
   val stateBTransaction = serviceHub.validatedTransactions.getTransaction(stateBStateAndRef.ref.txhash)!!
   ```
3. Load the states corresponding to the inputs of the loaded transaction

   ```
   val consumedInputs = stateBTransaction.inputs.map { stateRef -> serviceHub.loadState(stateRef) }
   ```